# how can find lync or its upgraded version skype installed in machine using vb script

Tags: vbscript

I am in requirement like show warning message to communicator user  saying "install lync ,OCS will decommisioned soon". before dispalying this warning message i need to check the microsoft lync 2013 or its upgrade skype is available in user machine.If both are not available then only message shown to user.

I use below code for checking Lync installaed or not. But message showing to user if they uses skype(upgrade of Lync).

Any help from Experienced hands will be great.

```
On Error Resume Next

Const HKLM = &H80000002 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

    strComputer = "."

    strKey = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"

    strEntry1a = "DisplayName"

    strEntry1b = "QuietDisplayName"

    strEntry1c = "DisplayVersion"

    strEntry1d = "UninstallString"

    IsLyncInstalled = 0 

    Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts://" & strComputer & "/root/default:StdRegProv")

    objReg.EnumKey HKLM, strKey, arrSubkeys
    'WScript.Echo "Installed Applications" & VbCrLf

    For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys

    intRet1 = objReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry1a, strValue1)

if intRet1 <> "" Then

objReg.GetExpandedStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry1a, strValue1

intCompare=StrComp("Microsoft Lync 2013",strValue1,vbTextCompare)

    IF intCompare = 0 THEN

IsLyncInstalled = 1

WScript.Echo "Microsoft Lync 2013 is  installed on this system" &VbCrLf  &strEntry1a & " : " & strValue1 


    END IF

End If

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than search through the registry, you may want to take a look at the [`Win32_Product`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378(v=vs.85).aspx) WMI class. It can identify the software installed on your PC and provides a number of properties that can be used to identify the vendor, version, etc.

Here's an example showing how to the query local machine and display some of `Win32_Product`'s properties. Run this using `cscript`:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colSoftware = objWMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product")

For Each objSoftware In colSoftware

    s = objSoftware.Caption & vbCrLf
    s = s & String(79, "=") & vbCrLf    
    s = s & "Description: " & objSoftware.Description & vbCrLf
    s = s & "Identifying Number: " & objSoftware.IdentifyingNumber & vbCrLf
    s = s & "Install Location: " & objSoftware.InstallLocation & vbCrLf
    s = s & "Install State: " & objSoftware.InstallState & vbCrLf
    s = s & "Name: " & objSoftware.Name & vbCrLf
    s = s & "Package Cache: " & objSoftware.PackageCache & vbCrLf
    s = s & "SKUNumber: " & objSoftware.SKUNumber & vbCrLf
    s = s & "Vendor: " & objSoftware.Vendor & vbCrLf
    s = s & "Version: " & objSoftware.Version & vbCrLf
    s = s & vbCrLf

    WScript.Echo s

Next
```

See if you can use `Caption`, `Name`, `SKUNumber`, `IdentifyingNumber`, `Version`, `Vendor`, or some other property to distinguish Lync from Skype.

Comment: HI Bond Thanks For your Information.Its resolve my above issue.

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to upvote and/or accept my answer if you think others will find it useful also.